Multiple additional queries through IFS and regexmatch
If any H. E. Operator or Heavy Driver has a Valid or Expiring Soon Aramco License (Column F), Column H should display the value of Column F, otherwise display the value of G or E respectively.

=ifs( 
  regexmatch(D24, "Crane Operator|Rigger I{1,3}"), F24, 
  D24 = "H.E. Operator", G24, 
  true, E24 
)


You can access Goggle Sheet to check the data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_jOn0vyv6osaoppeU9TXX1boOlZbnoCFy3eWsddP7uc/edit?gid=14738129#gid=14738129
Regards,
